# Entity Framework Context 6.1.3 not Refreshed / Destroyed?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing

In this unittest I will verify that the MD5 of the Content byte column is calculated, persisted and fetched correctly.

However, it seems that the Entity Framework (6.1.3) context is not refreshed / destroyed, since after the raw SQL UPDATE that clearly takes effect, but not shown when fetching the row with a new context.

```
namespace UnitTests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class TestDataPacketServiceDebug
    {
        [TestInitialize]
        public void Setup()
        {
            CommonMethods.ResetDatabase();
            try
            {
                CommonMethods.ResetDataPacketDirectory();
            }
            catch (DirectoryNotFoundException)
            {
            }
        }

        [TestCategory("DataPacketService"), TestMethod]
        public void TestGetLocalFilePathDebug()
        {
            // Persist a DataPacket
            int dataPacketId;
            using (var testDBContext = new TestDBContext())
            {
                DataPacket dataPacket = new DataPacket
                {
                    Content = File.ReadAllBytes(@"Resources\SampleResources.zip"),
                    Description = "DataPacketSample consist of some random found .DLL files on disk",
                    Name = "SampleResources",
                    Version = "1"
                };
                testDBContext.DataPackets.Add(dataPacket);
                testDBContext.SaveChanges();
                dataPacketId = dataPacket.DataPacketId;
            }

            // Verify file path extraction
            using (var testDBContext = new TestDBContext())
            {
                DataPacket dataPacket = DataPacketService.GetByNameAndVersion("SampleResources", "1",
                    testDBContext);

                string extractedFilePath = DataPacketService.GetLocalFilePath(testDBContext,
                    dataPacket, "EntityFramework.dll");

                string validDestinationPath = String.Format(@"{0}\DataPackets\{1}_v{2}\EntityFramework.dll",
                    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, dataPacket.Name, dataPacket.Version);

                Assert.AreEqual(validDestinationPath, extractedFilePath);

                if (File.Exists(extractedFilePath) == false)
                {
                    Assert.Fail("SampleResources was not extracted correctly");
                }
            }
            // When setting a breakpoint here and take a look with external SQL Browser
            // (e.g. Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio), following is in order:
            // Note! Not all columns are shown
            // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            // DataPacketId | Name            | RowVersion | Content     | MD5                      | Version
            //            1 | SampleResources | NULL       | 0x504B03... | 2zSV8IChaiyf0UfnezDHKg== | 1


            // Manually modify MD5 field in database for MD5 verification
            using (var testDBContext = new TestDBContext())
            {
                string sqlUpdate = String.Format("UPDATE dbo.DataPackets SET MD5 = 'another_MD5' WHERE DataPacketId = {0}",
                    dataPacketId);
                testDBContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sqlUpdate);
            }
            // When setting a breakpoint here we can clearly see that the row has been changed:
            // Note! Not all columns are shown
            // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            // DataPacketId | Name            | RowVersion | Content     | MD5         | Version
            //            1 | SampleResources | NULL       | 0x504B03... | another_MD5 | 1

            // Verify MD5
            using (var testDBContext = new TestDBContext())
            {   
                // Fetch dataPacket with modified MD5
                DataPacket dataPacket = DataPacketService.GetByNameAndVersion("SampleResources", "1", testDBContext);

                // Verify that the raw SQL command has been successful:
                Assert.AreEqual("another_MD5", dataPacket.MD5);
                // BANG!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                // Result Message:  Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:< another_MD5 >.Actual:< 2zSV8IChaiyf0UfnezDHKg== >.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Entity:**

```
public class DataPacket
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Identifier
    /// </summary>
    public int DataPacketId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Concurrency Token
    /// </summary>
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Name
    /// </summary>
    public string Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Description of data packet
    /// </summary>
    public string Description { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Version of data packet
    /// </summary>
    public string Version { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// MD5 of the data packet (i.e. MD5 of Content byte array)
    /// </summary>
    public string MD5 { get; private set; }

    private byte[] content;

    /// <summary>
    /// Byte content of the data packet (i.e. 
    /// </summary>
    public byte[] Content
    {
        get { return content; }
        set
        {
            content = value;
            UpdateMD5();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// TestCase navigation DataPacket <== One-To-Many ==> TestCases
    /// </summary>
    public ICollection<TestCase> TestCases { get; set; } // DataPacket <== One-To-Many ==> TestCases

    /// <summary>
    /// Update MD5 checksum depending on content
    /// </summary>
    private void UpdateMD5()
    {
        if (content != null)
        {
            this.MD5 = GetMD5ForBytes(content);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get MD5 checksum for content byte array
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="content">Content byte array</param>
    /// <returns>MD5 checksum</returns>
    public static String GetMD5ForBytes(byte[] content)
    {
        if (content != null)
        {
            System.Security.Cryptography.MD5 md5Object = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create();
            return System.BitConverter.ToString(md5Object.ComputeHash(content)).Replace("-", "");
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

**GetByNameAndVersion**

```
public static DataPacket GetByNameAndVersion(string name, string version, TestDBContext testDBContext)
        {
            IQueryable<DataPacket> query = testDBContext.Set<DataPacket>();
            query = query.Where(t => t.Name == name).Where(t => t.Version == version);
            return query.Single();
        }
```

Note! I am using a localDB database.

Comment: I don't think anything wrong with EF, most probably somewhere in your `DataPacketService.GetByNameAndVersion` implementation, for example MD5 recalculates instead of reading from db etc, or for example your tests have some issues with transactions etc - hard to say without whole picture.

Comment: Need to show us GetByNameAndVersion code indeed.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the question =)

Comment: What is inside `CommonMethods`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a EF context issue (it works as expected), but incorrect test / logic in your `DataPacket` class.

You have two related properties, both mapped to database table columns:

```
/// <summary>
/// MD5 of the data packet (i.e. MD5 of Content byte array)
/// </summary>
public string MD5 { get; private set; }

private byte[] content;

/// <summary>
/// Byte content of the data packet (i.e. 
/// </summary>
public byte[] Content
{
    get { return content; }
    set
    {
        content = value;
        UpdateMD5();
    }
}
```

The client C# code can only set the `Content` which in turn updates the `MD5` - fine. But what happens when EF loads the entity from the database? Indeed, it uses the same property setters (the `private` is not a problem because EF uses reflection / code generation, so it can call externally any type of setter).

Now everything depends on the *order* of calling setters. In your case the `MD5` is called first, then the `Content`. Since your SQL command updated the `MD5` column, but left `Content` unchanged, the first setter will set the `MD5` value from the database, and the second setter will update it back from the `Content`. Which of course is causing the assertion to report failure.

It's up to you to decide whether updating the `MD5` column in database through SQL is valid operation (basically leaving the `MD5` and `Content` out of sync). The order of calling the property setters in undefined - currently if you move the `MD5` property declaration after the `Content` property, the test will pass, but it's something you cannot rely on.

Comment: That sounds very reasonable! Thanks you for the good and simple explanation =) Was trying to Bounty +50 but it says that i have to wait 17h, will do that.