# What is the use of EF Core's "backing fields"?

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core

EF Core 1.1.0 [has support for](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/backing-field) "backing fields". Which means EF uses a field rather than a property to write data to.

It seems useful for migrating legacy code. Are there any other good use cases?

Comment: "I don't yet understand what is its purpose? It seems useful for migrating legacy code" those two sentences contradict each other. You've identified at least one purpose. Why isn't that enough?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Well done, argue semantics, rather than answer the question. I've edited it to remove the contradiction. Are there any other use cases?

Comment: The usage is when the property getter and/or setter contains some logic. See for instance this EF6 issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43337710/entity-framework-context-6-1-3-not-refreshed-destroyed. It's hard (if possible at all) to be solved with EF6, but easy with EF Core being configured to use backing fields when materializing the entity.